# PostgreSQL doesn't use index on inherited tables

Tags: postgresql, index, partitioning, performance, inheritance, postgresql-performance

I have two tables in PostgreSQL 9.4.5 deployed on Amazon RDS:

- an append only, weekly partitioned, All Positions table. These store all position readings from about 100,000 sensors. There are about 50 million records per week (80 records per second), with about 2 weeks of data so far (100 million records). This table is used to retrieve the historical positions of any individual sensor
- a Current Positions table, which stores the latest reading from any sensor by it's primary key. An update trigger updates which row stores the latest reading from a sensor.

Definition for All Positions:

```
CREATE TABLE all_positions
(
  pk BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  sensor_id UUID,
  rcv_tme TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,

  -- many other fields...
)

CREATE TABLE all_positions_y2016w01 (
    CHECK (rcv_tme >= '2016-01-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND 
            rcv_tme < '2016-01-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
) INHERITS (all_positions);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX all_positions_y2016w01_pk_index ON all_positions_y2016w01(pk)

CREATE TABLE all_positions_y2016w02 (
    CHECK (rcv_tme >= '2016-01-11 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND 
            rcv_tme < '2016-01-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
) INHERITS (all_positions);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX all_positions_y2016w02_pk_index ON all_positions_y2016w02(pk)

-- ... other weekly tables

-- upserts into current_position table the latest pk for a sensor_id
CREATE TRIGGER insert_positions_current_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON all_positions
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_positions_current_function();

-- bins into appropriate child table
CREATE TRIGGER insert_positions_partition_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON all_positions
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_positions_partition_function();
```

and Current Positions:

```
CREATE TABLE current_positions
(
  sensor_id UUID,
  pk BIGINT
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX current_positions_sensorid_idx on current_positions(sensor_id)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX current_positions_pk_idx on current_positions(pk)
```

The issue is when I perform the following query:

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE
 SELECT t1.*
   FROM current_positions t2
     INNER JOIN all_positions t1 ON t1.pk = t2.pk
```

it performs a seq scan of all child tables i.e. 100 million rows which takes 7 minutes.

But if I perform the following query (assuming that only week 1 and week 2 hold all the records):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
(SELECT t1.*
  FROM current_positions t2
    INNER JOIN all_positions_y2016w01 t1 ON t1.pk = t2.pk)
  UNION
(SELECT t1.*
  FROM current_positions t2
    INNER JOIN all_positions_y2016w02 t1 ON t1.pk = t2.pk)
```

it performs an index scan on the child tables, and takes about 2 seconds.

I believe this is because the tables are partitioned by time, and PostgreSQL doesn't understand that the pk column is unique across all the child tables i.e. for each (sensor_id, pk) record in current_positions, there will only be one corresponding record which matches pk across all the all_position child tables. Is there any way to force an index scan on the child tables, instead of a seq scan?

Thanks!

Note: I've linked the two EXPLAIN ANALYZE below

http://explain.depesz.com/s/qvJj

http://explain.depesz.com/s/fFwr

Comment: Would defining a foreign key constraint give enough of a hint to the planner?

Comment: I've considered that, but apparently it's not possible in Postgres http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360312/foreign-keys-table-inheritance-in-postgresql

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `CREATE TABLE LIKE` instead of inheriting the master table? It seems like `INHERITS` is most useful if you're either changing the parent tables, or inheriting from multiple parents.

Comment: Inheritance is also used for partitioning and constraint exclusion, which I require for some my queries: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate, since constraint exclusion is the opposite of what you want in this instance. You might also be able to work around this by creating a view (with the working SQL) and updating it at the same time you create a new partition. Postgres helpfully offers `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` here.